# Regex : Evaluating part of the expression

Tags: ruby, regex

Let's say

```
sometext= "text text picture 1 picture 2 text text"
```

I want to write an expression that grabs the block of text before the pictures, and the first two pictures. Sometimes there will be only one picture but could be as many as five.

My first attempt was

```
parsed = sometext.scan(/picture.*?(picture.*?(?=picture))
```

But it appears that Ruby does not support Regex if then statements.

[I edited this question to make it more clear.]

Comment: Could you add some inputs and outputs that you expect?

Comment: Sure.  sometext= "text goodtext picture 1 text text picture 2 text text" result is "goodtext picture 1 picture 2"  also could be sometext= "text goodtext picture 1 text text" result is "goodtext picture 1"

Comment: So, there's a word, followed by "picture <digit>" upto 5 times?

Comment: The problem is it's not very consistent.  I'm trying to scrape a website and the format is, a heading, and some pictures.  At most I want each heading and two pictures but occasionally there will be only one per heading.  There might be 10 headings on a page, so this pattern will repeat down the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I wound up doing.  I grabbed the whole chunk in one line of code and stuck it in an array.

```
var = sometext.scan(/goodtext.*?endofsection/m)
```

and then in another line made an array out of the chunks.  I know the heading is first and an undetermined number of pictures follow, so I then limit the array down to three items.

```
var = var.collect{|x| x.scan(/heading|image).slice(0..2)}
```

I need to refine this more by gsub out the stuff other stuff I don't need, but I think this will satisfy my criteria.   If anyone else can think of a more elegant way of doing this, I'm all for it.

Answer (score 3):

Here are various solutions, all of which give the same results:

```
ids = sometext.scan(/picture (\d+)/).flatten.map(&:to_i)
ids = sometext.scan(/(picture (\d+))/).map{ |str,id| id.to_i }
ids = sometext.scan(/(picture (\d+))/).map(&:last).map(&:to_i)
p ids
#=> [1, 2]
```